# MKStore iPhone Dev Help

Tags: iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to use the MKStore code for my in-app purchases. The readme, and other documentation doesn't go too much into detail for configuration.

in MKStoreManager.h, I need to configure this:

```
// CONFIGURATION STARTS -- Change this in your app
#define kConsumableBaseFeatureId @"com.mycompany.myapp."
#define kFeatureAId @"com.mycompany.myapp.featureA"
#define kConsumableFeatureBId @"com.mycompany.myapp.005"
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm supposed to put here.  In the readme it states that I need to use this to trigger in-app purchases:

```
[[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeature:@"exampleConsumable"];
```

This code works fine, the user can purchase the consumable, but then application crashes and will SIBABRT when the MKStoreManager is initialized in applicationDidFinishLaunching if I try to run the application again.

So, I'm assuming the app is crashing because I neglected to configure the 3 "#define" lines correctly - and I'm not really sure what to put there.  Do I have to define every in-app purchase there?

For example, say I have 3 in-app purchases. The Product IDs of them being: "itemOne", "itemTwo", and "itemThree".  The bundle identifier for the actual app being "exampleApp". All of the in-app purchases being consumable - How would I go about setting this up?

If anyone could give me a quick walkthrough on how to configure this I would really, really, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Apply class with nunmbers, as it is the new style: item1, item2, item3
Dont use any prefixes.